# Pycharm on Linux: Scrolling has become suddenly very sluggish

Tags: virtualbox, performance, scrolling, pycharm, mobaxterm

I've a Linux machine with 4gb of RAM and 2 VCPUs on VirtualBox running on a Windows 7 host (Core i7 with 16 gigs of RAM). The Linux VM is my workspace for a project. I run Mobaxterm on my Windows machine, and I set the DISPLAY for my Linux machine that runs PyCharm to this.

It was working without any issues for a long time, but since yesterday I see scrolling has become very sluggish and PyCharm has become very slow in general. I can literally see the Swing components getting painted as I scroll up and down or open any dialog boxes.

I've tried:

- Restarting the VM and the Windows host
- Deleted `.idea` and `~/.PyCharm40` directories and recreated my projects
- Instead of using a bridged network in VirtualBox, I tried connecting via the Host-only-adapter (to avoid touching the company LAN).
- Increased -Xms and -Xmx settings for Pycharm
- Tried using Firefox on this Linux VM, and then tested if the scrolling or the UI was sluggish there using the same DISPLAY (it wasn't); tried loading a big page and the scrolling was smooth
- Turned off all code inspections in PyCharm (IDE was put on Power Saving mode)
- Uninstalled (removed PyCharm, all `.idea` directories and `~/.PyCharm40` directory) and tried reinstalling
- Uninstalled MobaXterm (with its configuraton) and tried after reinstalling it

And yet, I don't see any improvements. I'm out of ideas on what to try and how to fix this. There's absolutely no performance issues on the Windows host. `top` shows reasonable CPU usage for PyCharm's Java process (between 5% and 15%; I think it's not bad?).

`uptime` doesn't show any high load as well:

```
$ uptime
 20:04:54 up 57 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem resolved, and I don't understand why it worked, so any explanation on this will be useful. I'm documenting this so anyone else who faces this problem can benefit.

What I was doing is, setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable in MobaXterm like this:

```
$ export DISPLAY=<my_windows_ip>:0.0
```

Apparently this is unnecessary according to MobaXterm documentation as it does the [forwarding on its own](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html).

So what fixed my issue:

```
> ssh my_linux_ip
$ pycharm
```

That's it. I didn't have to set the DISPLAY variable explicity. However, this didn't work for my colleague who's facing the same issue.

**UPDATE:**

Finally resolved the issue on my colleague's computer as well. It was because of a CPU setting of his Linux VM on VirtualBox that was the cause of this issue.

Steps:

- Launch Oracle VirtualBox Manager
- Click on the concerned VM `->` Settings
- System `->` Processor
- Drag Execution Cap to 100%

His previous Execution Cap setting was at 44%.